# Disable Windows Metro Scrollbar Timeout

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, modern-ui

Is it possible to disable disappearance of scrollbars in Windows Metro apps?

I find that using Metro from a non-touch PC is very frustrating. Here's my typical routine in Windows desktop apps that doesn't work well in Metro:

1. Place the mouse cursor on the scrollbar
2. Read for a spell
3. Click the left mouse button (typically on the laptop touchpad)

In Metro, at this point the scrollbar has disappeared. Now I've got to move the mouse to make the scrollbar reappear and then left click.

Is there maybe a registry entry that can disable this or give the option to set the timeout to, say, a thousand years?

Edit:
This has come over to Windows 10 as well; it's not just Metro any more.

Comment: Why not use the touchpad's scroll functionality?

Comment: I've tried that, but it is cumbersome in comparison to clicking the button. In searching the internet, I see that I'm not the only one who does things this way.

Comment: Who would have thought that Microsoft would make a permanent move away from usability?